# Update or replace a document field (array) item with a filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document likes the following:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('AAABBBCCC'),
    'content': 'This is content.'
    'votes': [
        { 'user': ObjectId('UserIdOfA'), 'value': 1 },
        { 'user': ObjectId('UserIdOfB'), 'value': 2 },
        { 'user': ObjectId('UserIdOfC'), 'value': 3 }
    ]
}
```

Every user can only have one vote. The user can change the vote or even remove the vote at anytime.
How do I build a query and update: 1. if votes array already has the user vote, set the value or replace the whole vote, 2. if there's no vote in the votes, insert it.

It was the code I tried but failed with 'Cannot update 'votes' and 'votes' at the same time' exception

```
public Task<UpdateResult> AddVoteAsync(ObjectId id, UserVote vote)
{
    var filter = Builders<Topic>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
    var update = Builders<Topic>.Update
        .PullFilter(x => x.Votes, Builders<UserVote>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UserId, vote.UserId))
        .AddToSet(x => x.Votes, vote);
    return this.collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Can this operation be done in only one request? Or the only way is to find the document first and later decide the way to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a more concise way to do it in one request with this data structure.

You could do it in one request if you changed the data structure to add a `votes` collection with the user, value, and an ObjectId of the parent content.

You could then do a simple `upsert` which would take care of doing everything in a single request. Getting all the votes would be a find query for all votes with the related parent content.